# Execute command if view exists

Tags: android, robotium

I'm using robotium to write tests for our android application. I'm looking to execute a command if a certain view or text exists. It would be ideal to check if the view/button exists, but I'm open to checking if the `logout` text exists as well

My (incorrect) pseudocode would be something like this:

```
if solo.getView("logoutButton")) //if the logout button exists
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView("logoutButton")); //click it
end
```

I'm not familiar with robotium or android and would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the good old findViewById:

```
View view = solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
Assert.assertNotNull(view);
solo.clickOnView(view);
```

Edit:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.view.View;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testView() throws Exception {
        View view = solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Assert.assertNotNull(view);
        solo.clickOnView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if the view doesn't exist `solo.clickOnView(view);`? Will it move on?

Comment: Additionally, getting `cannot resolve symbol` for `R` and `Assert` -- is there some import I need to do?

Comment: @theartofbeing if the view doesn't exists, assert and your whole test will fail at the second line. It will stop. I'll update my question with my test code, maybe it'll help you.

Comment: Awsome, that fixed assert, but still getting the error on the `R` in `(R.id.logout_button)`

Comment: @theartofbeing make sure the id matches the view in your layout. Also you might need to rebuils your project.

Comment: Rebuilt the project, but still getting the error `package R does not exist` -- I'm not familiar with the syntax, but where is coming from?